# How to execute a raw union SQL query on several tables with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, ajax, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm programming a web application with intentionally implemented vulnerabilities for a CTF competition and I'm using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core with a SQLite database. I want to make a SQL injection possible and in order to that, I need to somehow query the database on several tables with an union statement.

Unfortunately all my attempts resulted in error messages. The backend controller takes an argument via an ajax request and the client should misuse the `UserId` variable and modify the parameters in the ajax request to get more information about another table.

I tried several `FromSql` approaches but none of them worked out. Does someone know how I can solve this?

This is the backend controller code

```
public JsonResult ListImagePaths(string UserId)
{
    string query = $"SELECT * FROM UserImage WHERE UID == {UserId}";

    var results = mContext.UserImage.FromSql(query);           

    return Json(results);
}
```

This way I only do a query on the `UserImage` table. I did not find a way to query two tables. I tried to create a `DbSet` that consists of attributes in both tables but this didn't work too.

This is the client side ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ListImagePaths/"27b988e3-77ab-41e4-b945-6ac9315a70ec"',
        success: function (result){
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
})
```

Here is a sample of the **UserImage** table

Uid    = 27b988e3-77ab-41e4-b945-6ac9315a70ec 
Path   = CloudImages/picture.jpg 
Id     = e802a368-229f-4ed5-ba84-42ce4da5ed0a

Here is a sample of the **AspNetUsers** table

Id                  = 81858e0d-e75f-45c5-8054-ef956e843a04 
UserName            = SomeGuy43 
NormalizedUserName  = SOMEGUY43 
Email               = myemail@somehere.com 
NormalizedEmail     = MYEMAIL@SOMEWHERE.COM 
EmailConfirmed      = 1 
PasswordHash        = uRGWeGWq5ZorrzgNvSuz8Q== 
SecuritySamp        = RBCZDCBA3IEMPET2ZCL4MVCXW3IA3H4C 
ConcurrencyStamp    = 0b8873cc-ecfe-4280-a6bf-0f354242f4a4 
PhoneNumber         = NULL 
PhoneNumberConfirmed= 0 
TwoFactorEnabled    = 0 
LockoutEnd          = 0 
LockoutEnabled      = 0 
AccessFailedCount   = 0 
AvatarImage         = pictures/avatar.jpg 
Salt                = 4r1rtuji0cc 
IsAdmin             = 0

Comment: I believe you can put `.Include` before the `FromSql` to include related tables?

Comment: I'm experimenting with `.Include` now.
`var results = mContext.UserImage.Include( u => u.Users)FromSql(query);`

But i can only access attributes of the UserImage table.

@mason The application should allow SQL-Incjections

Comment: Please provide an example of the tables you want to `UNION`. e.g. at least two sample entity classes representing tables.

Comment: I have edited the post and added two samples.

Comment: But these have nothing in common - they are more like candidates for `JOIN` rather than `UNION`. I am expecting to see the classes you used in  *I tried to create a DbSet that consists of attributes in both tables*, i.e. the two entity classes and the class with the common attributes.

Comment: I thought a union statement allows for 2 select queries in a row? Because when I query the database without EF in-between it perfectly works. I just have to make sure, that the amounts of columns are equal. So the query `Select * from AspNetUsers union select Uid Path Id null null null null .... from UserImage` worked without problems.

Comment: The same should be with EF. What actually doesn't work?

Comment: I got several error messages. After I tried it just once again I got the message : 
`The data is NULL at ordinal 14. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.`   This time I made the `fromsql` call on the Users table like that : `mContext.Users.FromSql($"Select * from AspNetUsers where Id =={UserId} union select Uid, Path, Id, null, null, null ... from UserImage")`

Answer (score 2):

> I did not find a way to query two tables. I tried to create a DbSet that consists of attributes in both tables but this didn't work too.

Not sure what exactly "didn't work", but this is the way to go. But instead of creating `DbSet` of the class containing the common attributes, thus telling EF to treat is an *entity*, create `DbQuery` or simply register that class as [query type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types).

For instance:

```
public class MyQueryType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    publc string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Inside your `DbContext` class, either:

```
public DbQuery<MyQueryType> MyQueryType { get; set; }
```

or (inside `OnModelCreating` override):

```
modelBuilder.Query<MyQueryType>();
```

Both will allow you to use `MyQueryType` as target for `FromSql`:

```
string query = $"SELECT Id, Path AS Text FROM UserImage WHERE UID == {UserId}"
    + $" UNION ALL SELECT Id, UserName AS Text FROM AspNetUsers";

var results = mContext.Query<MyQueryType>().FromSql(query);
```

Just make sure the SQL query returns the expected column names and types by using aliases as shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally worked. I am relieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM UserImage WHERE UID == convert(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, convert(varchar(max),{UserId}))";
```

I want to emphasize that it is not performatic to use the * it is better to use the columns.

Comment: What should I choose for UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Comment: The `FromSql` method doesn't allow queries on specific columns... That's why I use `*`